# How to search for users using the VK API without logging in to VK

Tags: search, oauth, vk

I have been trying to find a way to let a user search for a specific community or user on VK and return the wall of the found user/community, without the need for a login dialog. The VK api documentation doesnt seem to specify a way to execute basic search functionality without having to log in to VK first and passing an acces token.

Is there a way to gain access to the search methods on VK. Or a different way to get a list of users that match the input of the user?

Thank you in advance!